# Bigquery RegExp extract only numbers from string

Tags: regex, re2

How do I extract only 1111111 from a product_name column like this in Bigquery:

```
AB~1111111|Omega | Shoes
```

I tried the following:

```
REGEXP_EXTRACT(product_name, r"^([0-9]+)|") AS Product_ID
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to use

```
REGEXP_EXTRACT(product_name, r"^\D*(\d+)") AS Product_ID
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/F406e1/2)

*Details*:

- `^` - string start
- `\D*` - zero or more non-digits
- `(\d+)` - Group 1: one or more digits.